# Why does whole application get reloaded(recompiled) multiple times?

Tags: docker, playframework, sbt

I have a Play application running on a Docker(2.0.0.3) container for development purposes via sbt run command.

Upon startup, it seems like the application is reloaded(compiled) multiple time for some reason which has never happened before moving to Docker.

Even when modifying only a single file triggers the reload automatically
(The application does not wait for a new request for reloading)

↓ output from the application on startup.

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 9999
[info] Loading global plugins from /root/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings for project project-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /root/path/to/project
[info] Loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] Resolving key references (33083 settings) ...
[info] Set current project to ProjecRoot (in build file:/path/to/base/)
[info] Updating dependentApp1...
[info] Updating dependentApp2...
[info] Updating dependentApp3...
[info] Updating dependentApp4...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp5...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp6...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp7...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp8...
[info] Updating dependentApp9...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp10...
[info] Updating dependentApp11...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp12...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp13...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp14...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Updating dependentApp1...
[info] Updating dependentApp2...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp3...
[info] Updating dependentApp4...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp5...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp7...
[info] Updating dependentApp6...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp8...
[info] Updating dependentApp9...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp11...
[info] Updating dependentApp10...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp12...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp13...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp14...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp1...
[info] Updating dependentApp2...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp3...
[info] Updating dependentApp4...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp5...
[info] Updating dependentApp6...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp7...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp8...
[info] Updating dependentApp9...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp10...
[info] Updating dependentApp11...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp12...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp13...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Updating dependentApp14...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies.
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
```

Host's *src* is mounted on container's */root/path/to/base*
then `sbt projectNmae/run` is executed as the container's entrypoint.

↓ docker-compose file for the application

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  service-name:
    working_dir: /path/to/base
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9999:9999"
    environment:
      JAVA_XMX: 2G
      JAVA_XSS: 2M
      SBT_OPTS: "-XX:MetaspaceSize=2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g"
    entrypoint: >
      sh -c 'sbt projectName/run -J-Dhttp.port=$${PORT} -J-Dconfig.file=$${CONFIG_FILE} -J-Dlogger.file=$${LOGGER_FILE} -jvm-debug 9999'
    volumes:
      - ../../src:/root/src
      - ../../.ivy2:/root/.ivy2
      - ../../.sbt:/root/.sbt
    stdin_open: true
```